# What is the Sparrow racing league and how do I join it?

Tags: destiny

Long story short, I'm a new player and I've recently hit 40. When poking around in the Tower I found the sparrow vendor. They have their own rep and new sparrows to purchase when you hit the different levels, but they don't ask me to join anything nor do they have a quest/mission.

What do I need to do to purchase these shiny new bikes?

Comment: the Sparrow Racing League is now (2016-12-25) open again, as part of *The* *Dawning* special event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sparrow Racing League](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/Article/14086/7_Sparrow-Racing-League) was a PVP game type that allowed players to race each other with their sparrows.

> The Sparrow Racing League will welcome competitors to participate in a six-player free-for-all death race through enemy territory. After the update goes live on December 8th, visit Amanda Holliday in the Tower. She’ll be your Quartermaster for the event. Grab a quest and some bounties. Then, take your mark on the starting line. You might also check in with Tess. Eververse Trading will have some flair to make the event a little more fun, and a little more stylish.

Unfortunately Bungie only kept the racing for three weeks

> The races run for three weeks. They conclude on December 29th

Comment: That's....legitimately disappointing.

Comment: @Telestia I will agree with you on that. I unfortunately was unable to participate also. I heard Bungie does intend on bringing it back eventually

Comment: I'd like to add that the sparrows are still available to be purchased with Silver.